# How does a Decision Tree split when two features are tied?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, decision-trees

Decision Trees split based on which feature and which cut-off value creates the largest mean decrease in impurity (assuming hyperparameter split="best", criterion="gini").
Now take for example, you have two identical columns in your dataset. For each split, both these columns will have an equal mean impurity decrease. How does the algorithm choose which feature to use?

I have tested this out with the Titanic dataset, and have found that both features have a non-zero feature importance, so they both have been used in at least one split:

```
X["Duplicate"] = X["Pclass"]

DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y)
DecisionTreeClassifier().feature_importances_
```

Inspecting the tree, I cannot find any specific patterns that indicate why one feature is chosen over another. Is it by random choice?

And is there any way to make it so that only one of these duplicate features is used in the algorithm? (without simply removing one of the duplicates)

*Note: This question specifically refers to the sklearn implementation of the decision tree algorithm.*

Comment: The following answer maybe helpful: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84343/random-selection-of-variables-in-each-run-of-python-sklearn-decision-tree-regre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docstring for the `random_state` parameter:

> The features are always
> randomly permuted at each split, even if `splitter` is set to
> `"best"`. [...] The best found split may vary across different
> runs, even if `max_features=n_features`. That is the case, if the
> improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits and one
> split has to be selected at random.

---

So

> Is it by random choice?

Yep.

> And is there any way to make it so that only one of these duplicate features is used in the algorithm? (without simply removing one of the duplicates)

Not readily.  This is one reason to consider removing highly correlated features even for a tree-based model.

Comment: I see, I missed this clear explanation in the documentation. Is this also the reason why it's recommended to remove correlated features before using RFECV? Since the feature importance is roughly distributed evenly between highly correlated features, it sometimes keeps both correlated features and hurts model performance. Of course the "sometimes" is a bit more nuanced than that, but is this the basic reasoning.

Comment: @AvanishM that's another question, but at the very least yes, there are things to think about for correlated features in feature selection.